# How to test ajax calls with webpack

Tags: javascript, ajax, mocking, karma-runner, webpack

I'm using webpack to build lib written in EcmaScript6. It triggers ajax calls so I need to check if everything is working as expected in tests. I'm using karma + mocha setup. I tried to lift [express](http://expressjs.com/) server for testing and to use tools like [fetchmock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetchmock), [mocked-backend](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocked-backend), [nock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nock). Each of them throws error when I try to require it. I've expected error with express, cause it's designed to work on backend, but the rest should work in the browser.

So I wonder if I'm doing something wrong or this libs isn't compatible with webpack. What's the best way to test ajax with karma and webpack.

My karma.conf.js:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({

    basePath: '',

    files: [
      'test/main/*.test.js'
    ],

    frameworks: ['mocha'],

    preprocessors: {
      'test/main/*.test.js': ['webpack']
    },

    reporters: ['mocha'],

    webpack: {
      debug: true,
      module: {
        loaders: [{
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: 'babel-loader?experimental'
        }]
      }
    },

    webpackMiddleware: {
      stats: false
    },

    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['PhantomJS']

  });
};
```

Comment: What's the error that it throws?  I've managed to get around it with a mini hack but I'm not certain that the approach I'm taking is the best one.